# How to associate ranges vertically with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to draw a chart whose:

- X-axis would be a google sheet row
- Y-axis another google sheet row.

I don't know why this is not a trivial case in Google sheet but indeed it does expects a column at least apparently.
To do it graphically I need to play a little with the chart settings (*TransposeRowsAndColumns* and *Associate ranges Vertically* as you can see in the french (sorry) screenshot).

Unfortunately this trick doesn't allow the reload of values in selected ranges. If I do so I loose my settings.
Anyway I would like to do it programmatically.

I found the setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true|false) function but not the the other one.

**So please help me figure out how to perform in Google Apps Script the graphical action "Associate ranges" --> "Vertically"**

[[image: Chart editor[1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setMergeStrategy(mergeStrategy)` method with the `MERGE_ROWS` merge type like this:

```
function createChart() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var range1 = sheet.getRange("Confirmés!E1:AF1");
   var range2 = sheet.getRange("Confirmés!E77:AF77");
   var chart = sheet.newChart()
       .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
       .addRange(range1)
       .addRange(range2)
       .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
       .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
       .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
       .build();
}
```

**Reference**

- [EmbeddedChartBuilder Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#settransposerowsandcolumnstranspose)

Comment: Thank YOU!! MERGE_ROWS actually for my use-case.

Comment: @GuillaumeB I have edited my answer and I'm glad the solution provided was of help to you! Cheers! :)